# find $(x,y,z)$ that minimizes $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(a_i x + b_i y+ c_i z)^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_{i} x + e_{i} y+ f_{i} z)^2}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus

We have

$$
C(x,y,z)= \frac{P(x,y,z)}{Q(x,y,z)}
$$

where

$$P = \sum_{i=1}^{N}(a_i x + b_i y+ c_i z)^2 $$
$$Q = \sum_{i=1}^{N}(d_{i} x + e_{i} y+ f_{i} z)^2$$

and $a_i, b_i, c_{i}, d_{i}, e_{i}, f_{i}$ are constant parameters defined for $1\leq i,j \leq N$.

What are the values of for $x,y,z$ that minimize $C(x,y,z)$?

For a solution to the two dimensional case, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2911177/solutions-to-fracq-partial-px-partial-x-fracp-partial-qx-partial-x-f/).

---

EDIT:

In matrix form one could write this as $C(\mathbf{x})=\frac{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{P}\mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{x}}$ where $\mathbf{x}$ is the $3$x$1$ vector of unknowns and $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ are $3$x$3$ constant matrices. I hope this helps to simplify.

---

EDIT 2:

For the more general case, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915695/minimize-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfp-mathbfx-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfq-math).

Comment: Your function $C$ is a quotient of homogeneous polynomials, so it will be invariant under rescaling. You may wish to attempt the following: restrict your function to the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^3$ and use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @KReiser that is correct. I tried that but the equations were a bit too messy and using Lagrange multipliers did not seem to considerably simplify it. Could you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Taking logarithm of $C(x)$ and differentiate, the condition for local extremum becomes $\frac{Px}{x^TPx} = \frac{Qx}{x^TQx}\iff  Px  = \lambda Qx$ for some $\lambda$. For such $x$, $C(x) = \lambda$. The problem reduces to finding the smallest eigenvalue of $Q^{-1}P$.

Comment: @achille-hui Yes that works perfectly! thanks. Would you like to write it down as an answer ?

Comment: @achille-hui would similar approach work for the more general case ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914875/find-x-that-minimizes-fractr-mathbfxt-mathbfp-mathbfxtr-mathbf