# Find $\mathbf{X}$ that minimizes ${tr(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{P}\mathbf{X})}/{tr(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{X})}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, numerical-methods, matrix-calculus

We have

$$C(\mathbf{X})=\frac{tr(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{P}\mathbf{X})}{tr(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{X})}$$
 where $\mathbf{X}$ is an $N$x$M$ matrix of unknowns and $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$ are $N$x$N$ constant matrices. We want to find $\mathbf{X}$ that minimizes $C$.

Solution for the special case of $M=1$ could be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914359/find-x-y-z-that-minimizes-frac-sum-i-1na-i-x-b-i-y-c-i-z2-su).

A corrected version of this question (adding orthonormality constraint on columns of $\mathbf{X}$ is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915695/minimize-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfp-mathbfx-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfq-math).

Comment: Is $M>1$ really that different? It is still quadratic in $x$ so you can rewrite it to an $M=1$ case.

Comment: btw, is there a way to calculate the smallest eigenvector efficiently ? (I know of the Power method for largest eigenvector). Here we could assume all the eigenvalues are positive I guess.

Comment: I think if we switch $P$ and $Q$ then we could use  Power method.

Comment: I think you are confused with the absolute values. The smallest eigenvalue could be found by the Power method if it is very negative.

Comment: I meant we are given that C is always positive, hence all the eigenvalues should be positive.

Comment: You have got to consider the region of minimization, what if $Q$ has a null space ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I would guess in that case the minimum would be zero.

Comment: And what if there is a common nullspace?

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915695.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define some new variables
$$\eqalign{
 A &= \tfrac{1}{2}(P+P^T),
\,\,\,\,\,B = \tfrac{1}{2}(Q+Q^T),
\,\,\,\,\,M = B^{-1}A
\cr
 \alpha &= {\rm tr}(X^TAX) \implies d\alpha=2AX:dX \cr
 \beta &= {\rm tr}(X^TBX) \implies d\beta=2BX:dX \cr
}$$
Write your function in terms of these new variables, then find the differential and gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
C(X) = \lambda &= \beta^{-1}\alpha \cr
d\lambda &= \beta^{-1}(d\alpha-\lambda\,d\beta) = 2\beta^{-1}(AX-\lambda BX):dX \cr
\frac{\partial C}{\partial X}
  = \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial X}
 &= 2\beta^{-1}(AX-\lambda BX) \cr
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve
$$\eqalign{
AX &= \lambda BX \cr
MX &= \lambda X \cr
Mv1^T &= \lambda v1^T \cr
}$$
This is the eigenvalue equation. So $\lambda\,$ is the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix $M$, $1$ is a vector of all ones, $v$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, and $X$ is a matrix whose columns are all identical and equal to $v$.

In the unlikely event that the matrix $M$ has several *different* eigenvectors all corresponding to the same *minimal* eigenvalue, then the columns of $X$ need not be identical but could consist of linear combinations of such eigenvectors.

**NB:** In some steps above, a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$

Comment: did you see that $x$ is a matrix?

Comment: Oops! Let me rethink this.

Comment: If we add the constraint that columns of $X$ are orthonormal, would the $M$ smallest eigenvectors be the solution? I posted it as a separate question to avoid confusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915695/minimize-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfp-mathbfx-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfq-math

Comment: @mghandi  If $M$ is hermitian (symmetric) then its eigenvectors are orthogonal, and your suggested solution is correct.  In the more likely event that $M\ne M^*$ then the problem is much harder, and probably does not have a closed-form solution.

Comment: I realized that the $M$ smallest eigenvectors would be the solution if we use $X^TQX=I$ constraint (suggested by  @loup-blanc).