# How to optimization the $f(X)= \| A - XX^T \|_F^2 + \| X \|_F^2 $ on Grassmann manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, grassmannian

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(X)= \| A - XX^T \|_F^2 +  \| X \|_F^2\\  \text{subject to} & X \in Gr(d,N)
\end{array}$$

where $Gr(d,N)$ means the [Grassmann Manifold](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/boumal14a/boumal14a.pdf);   $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm; $X \in R^{N \times d}$ and $A \in R^{N \times N}$ is symmetric.

My question is how to optimize above objective on Grassmann manifold? what step do we need?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can add term punishing $X$ more the further away from manifold it lies.

Comment: What are the dimensions of $A,X$ ? Say that $d\leq N$. $X\in Gr$ is non-sense; say that $X$ has full rank. Is $A$ symmetric ?

Comment: @loupblanc, $X$ has the full rank and $A$ can be symmetric.  Is that $d \le N$ is necessary? I am not familiar with Grassmann manifold

Comment: @mathreadler I add some change to constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume $d\leq N$ and $A$ symmetric $\ge 0$. If you use the construction of 3.1 in

http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2017/papers/Wang_Grassmannian_Manifold_Optimization_CVPR_2017_paper.pdf

then your problem is equivalent to

$\text{minimize} \; f(X)= \| A - XX^T \|_F^2 +  \| X \|_F^2\;  \text{subject to} \; X^TX=I_d$.

Since you use the Frobenius norm, we can do explicitly the job. Indeed $f(X)=tr(A^2+2XX^T)-2tr(X^TAX)$; since $tr(A^2+2XX^T)$ is constant, the problem reduces to find

$\text{maximize} \; g(X)= tr(X^TAX)\;  \text{subject to} \; X^TX=I_d$.

Let $spectrum(A)=\lambda_1\geq  \cdots \geq \lambda_N\geq 0$.

$\textbf{Proposition}$. The max of $g$ is reached for $X=[u_1,\cdots,u_d]$ where $u_j$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated to $\lambda_j$.

$\textbf{Proof}$. cf my post (EDIT 4BIS) in

[Minimize ${tr(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{P}\mathbf{X})}/{tr(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{X})}$ s.t. $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{I}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915695/minimize-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfp-mathbfx-tr-mathbfxt-mathbfq-math/2919404#2919404)

It suffices to adapt the proof of Proposition 2 when the order of the $(\lambda_i)$ is reversed.